# React app not communicating with my Django API on heroku

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, heroku

I deployed my react app and Django app to Heroku. Django serves the API and React serves as frontend.

The frontend part is working quite well but just seems not to be communicating with the Django side.
My project is set up as

[image: this].

If I try to access the database it [image: shows this].

Now, I'm confused if I'm to use http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/ to access it or its meant to be a Herokuapp domain/8000 to fetch the API. I've done allowed Host on the Django side as well as whitelist, CorsMiddleware and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST also used proxy on the package.json but everything still looks messed up and not communicating between each other

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access your local instance from production. You should be using the Heroku URI

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias. This is the url https://reacttarcks.herokuapp.com but this serves the frontend, I've tried using https://reacttarcks.herokuapp.com:8000 and https://reacttarcks.herokuapp.com/graphql, still doesn't work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean you get the same error when you use the Heroku address? Are you sure that's the right address? The right port?

Comment: Just double-checked.  The URL is correct. But its the Django part I'm not sure of. But when it was on my local server, I could access it via http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/. So I expected it should be either http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/ or http://reacttarcks.herokuapp.com:8000/graphql/